# Finding height of a tree without right and left references

Tags: java, tree

I've been trying to get the height of the root of 2 trees (same root). I just started working with trees and this way of traversing them without left or right references is causing me some difficulty.

I used the recursion to get to the leaf nodes then I tried to calculate the height via getParent() and a counter.

```
  public int height(){ 
  //code is a little messy but the first number is the height of the root
           System.out.print("Height: ");
            return height(root);
         }

 private int height(TNode tn){
 if (tn == null) return 0;
       int counter = 0;
        //recursive call to get to the leaf nodes
        for (TNode cn: tn.getChildren()){
              height(cn);

        }//while at the leaf nodes, count the parent nodes of the leaf nodes

       while(tn.getParent() != null){ //if there's a parent
        tn = tn.getParent(); //tn becomes its parent
        counter+=1;
        if(tn.getParent() == null && tn == root){
        counter+=1;   
        }
      }  
      System.out.print(counter + " ");

           return counter;
```

}

The heights of the 2 trees are 4 and 2.
The codes yields

Height: 4 4 4 3 3 4 4 4 3 2 3 3 3 2 2 0

Height: 2 2 2 0

I've tried using stacks and arrays to isolate the 4 and 2 at the beginning but to no avail. Maybe the issue is obvious but maybe my understanding of tree traversal in this manner is a little lacking. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "without right and left references"?  Is it that your nodes can have more than 2  children?

Comment: You know how most code that involve trees have Node left, right; which traverse the tree from the left and right subtrees respectfully? That's what I mean. I'm just trying to get the height without those references.

Comment: OK, you've _got_ left and right links, you're just not _calling_ them "left" and "right.  No matter, the problem is the same: you're recursively calling `height` to compute the height of each node's children and simply throwing away the result.  Computing the height at each leaf by backtracking up the parent link chain doesn't get around that problem and just makes things slower. All you need is this recursive definition: 1) height of a `null` node is zero; 2) height of a non-`null` node is 1 plus the height of the highest child.